# Prevent events from being queued

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm programmatically manipulating the window's `Selection` synchronously up to thousands of time. This queues up thousands of `selectionchange` event tasks, locking up the event loop.

Is there a way to temporarily pause queueing up certain (or all) events?

Example:

```js
document.onselectionchange = () => console.log('SC');

const selection = getSelection();
for (let i = 0; i < 1500; i++) {
  selection.modify('extend', i%2 ? 'backward' : 'forward', 'character');
}

setTimeout(() => console.log('Timeout'), 0)
console.log('SyncDone')
```

This doesn't work in a snippet. Copy it to the console, select anything on screen, and run it.

It'll take a couple of seconds to complete, blocking any other tasks, but the page will remain responsive.

Comment: You will need to remove the listener and then re-add it when you're done. Use `addEventListener` for better control over the listeners assigned to an element.

Comment: @pilchard Even without the listener it takes almost the same amount of time for Chrome to dispatch all the `selectionchange` events. Try it the same code block minus adding the listener.

Comment: Try it in a google search result page, with 3000 iterations.

Comment: "*I'm programmatically manipulating the window's `Selection` up to thousands of time.*" - why?

Comment: @Bergi The `Selection` object's stringifier is the only accessible method that can differentiate rendered text and exclude hidden whitespaces in text nodes. I'm using it to parse what's on screen and get their positions.

Comment: So are there any @Bergi JS tricks to access and control the task queue? 

Comment: @Brother58697 when removing and re-adding the listener at 10000 iterations I'm getting times of 350ms (imperceptible). This feels very much like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), what are you actually trying to solve?